# Redux slow performance

Tags: reactjs, redux

My websocket gets "a lot" of data in short bursts, say up to 1000 objects in 1-2s and for each I have to do this(to add to store): `dispatch({ type: NEW, payload })`

And the actual reducer(using FBs immutability helper):

```
case NEW:
  return update(state, {
    data: {
      [action.payload.tree.name]:
     { $push: [action.payload.name] },
    },
  });
```

Adding 10 items at once works fine, 100 take few seconds and 1000 pretty much overloads my chrome running on latest hardware.

I also struggle to understand why when adding 100 items for example, it doesn't re-render page and display each as it's added to store... but instead waits until all that came in "burst" are added.

Answer (score 2):

Consider batching your updates before hitting the dispatcher, and modify your action to accept consolidated arrays of updates rather than individual updates.

Comment: Could you please suggest something to optimize or avoid copying large objects? I have object (map of 'id => object') with 10k keys (historical chart) and it's very slow in the very last stage - reducer. Other parts (even sorting and merging data from batched API requests) are optimized and made as microtasks (via setTimeout), but I really don't know what to do with object assignment...

Comment: Found discussion with some possible solutions: https://github.com/reactjs/redux/issues/606

Comment: How did you identify the bottleneck as the reducer? Could it be the DOM updates that happen after your store is updated? If DOM updates is the key, do look into windowed rendering where only items in the viewport are updated. If it's really in the reducer, does your data really need to live in the store or can it stay in local state/props etc?

Comment: I used profiling a lot). I'm sure, that bottleneck in assigning props to object (using for-in, Object.assign or { ...obj }). And yes, good advice to use window updates (sliding window for chart) to show only part of data - I have implemented it already and it helps a lot to make UI more responsive. Following discussion on GH I mentioned above - I agree, that the best way to overcome this kind of issues is to place data outside of store and process it manually, using any needed optimization (e.g. modifying object in place, but set to store it's version/hash to notify all dependent components)